# Triggering another job with a Run Parameter

Tags: jenkins

I have a parameterized job with a run parameter which for now is called RUN_PARAMETER.  When I trigger it manually, the RUN_PARAMETER environment variable is set to the URL of the build that was selected.  In addition to RUN_PARAMETER, I also get I get RUN_PARAMETER.jobName, RUN_PARAMETER.number, RUN_PARAMETER_JOBNAME, RUN_PARAMETER_NAME, RUN_PARAMETER_NUMBER, and RUN_PARAMETER_RESULT environment variables set to the appropriate values for the selected build.

But I cannot get that to work when I trigger the job from another job.  From a pipeline job, I trigger my job with the run parameter, and I set the RUN_PARAMETER parameter equal to the URL of the appropriate build.

In the triggered job, the RUN_PARAMETER environment variable is exactly the same as it was when I triggered it manually, but none of the other environment variables (RUN_PARAMETER.jobName, RUN_PARAMETER.number, RUN_PARAMETER_RESULT, etc.) are set.

Is there a way to get those other environment variables set when I trigger the job from another job the same way they're set when I trigger it manually?

Comment: I am not an expert in Jenkins, but how do you populate your other parameters (e.g. `RUN_PARAMETER.jobName`)? PS: Edit your post, it's not laconic.

Comment: Those other parameters are populated automatically by the Run Parameter.  When it sets one, it sets them all.

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically" -- is it your own code that defines these variables?

Comment: No.  I mean that you create a job with a Run Parameter, all of those environment variables are set by the Run Parameter.